# firebase version is not updating through <npm install -g firebase-tools>

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

i am windows user and trying to update firebase version using 
**npm install -g firebase-tools** but when i run **firebase --version**
it shows the same version. 
I also run npm uninstall **firebase --save** and check **firebase --version** it shows same. 
what should i do to update my firebase version?

Answer (score 34):

`npm update -g firebase-tools`

or

`npm install -g firebase-tools@3.12.0` to install a specific version

And make sure to restart your **terminal/IDE** otherwise, it won't take effect.

Comment: The restart tip was the missing piece of the puzzle - Highly frustrating popular IDEs don't automatically reload bash configurations. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried `npm update -g firebase-tools`? This worked for me.

Comment: just keep getting 'command not found'

Answer (score 7):

These days if you're on an older version, and you check the version of **`firebase-tools`**, by running:

> **`firebase -V`**

along with the version of `firebase-tools` that you're on, it also gives you a messages, something like this:

[image]

> So you can basically run **`npm i -g firebase-tools`** to update the version of your **`firebase-tools`** installation to the latest version.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: With `npm install -g firebase-tools` I am getting `npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142` Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That might happen in case you've installed the `firebase-cli` using a so called **automatic install script**.

Try to call `curl -sL https://firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash` as described in [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#update-cli)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked on my case. No npm made it.

Answer (score 1):

For other like me stumbling in with a weird version mismatch:

When I did `firebase -V` in my terminal I would get a different version (5.1.1) than when I ran firebase through a `npm run` script (3.19.3)

The problem was that I had previously installed firebase locally into that project. In other words, I was getting the global version in the terminal, but npm was using the `node_modules` version

To confirm this, I added a simple test called test-foo to my package.json (`firebase -V && which firebase`) and ran it:

```
kuzyn(λ)matebox‡ npm run test-foo
kuzyn-project@1.1.0 test-foo /home/kuzyn/code/kuzyn-project/firebase
firebase -V && which firebase
3.19.3
/home/kuzyn/code/kuzyn-project/firebase/node_modules/.bin/firebase
```

Then I removed the (uneeded in my case) local firebase package from the `package.json` and from `node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

I tried several ways too and found this solution. I hope I helped to solve your problem.

```
 curl -sL https://firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 2 steps bellow 
1. yarn/npm cache clean
2. npm install -g firebase firebase-tools or yarn add -g firebase firebase-tools
 in a new terminal, firebse --version 
works for me

Answer (score 0):

it works to me...
standalone binary: Download the new version, then replace it on your system
if you are using the standalone.[Download the new version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using an old node version (v10) and had to switch to a newer one (v12). After that I ran `npm install -g firebase-tools` again and it was updated to the latest version.

You can check the current node version by running `node -v`. And I use `nvm` to switch to a different node version.