# How do I resolve the "firebase init firestore" error

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Anytime I run

```
firebase init firestore
```

I get this error

> Error: It looks like you haven't used Cloud Firestore in this project before. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/cresblog-3c03f/firestore to create your Cloud Firestore database.

but other firebase features works fine.

Comment: [I came here looking for the same issue, found this link which resolved my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219074/can-not-initialize-existing-firebase-project-from-cli-because-it-tells-me-i-do-n)