# Google firestore can't set Default GCP resource location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to initialise a Firestore project and am getting the following error from `firebase init firestore`:

*"It looks like you haven't used Cloud Firestore in this project before"*.

I have run the command using an existing project in which I have set up a working Firestore through the web interface (I am able to add documents to it).

I've also tried creating a new project through the CLI but I get the same error.

I have successfully run `firebase init functions` and `firebase init emulators` but can't get firestore to initialise.

This looks like the same problem described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962297/why-do-i-keep-receiving-an-error-when-initializing-my-firebase-project-while-set) and indeed in the settings page, *"Default GCP resource location"* appears to be *"Not yet selected"*.

[image]

However, when I click on the pencil to edit the value, the field has a (greyed-out) value of *"eur3 (europe west)"*.

[image]

It's not clear whether this value has actually been set or not as it is supposed not to be editable once set. In any case, I can't initialise my project with Firestore.

Comment: I had no trouble initialising the project with a Realtime Database so I guess I'll have to work with that.

Comment: Have you already checked this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4254)?